# Multiple d3.js force layout instances

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using http://bl.ocks.org/danielatkin/57ea2f55b79ae686dfc7 with some modifications and it is working great. But I want to have two instances of this working independently of each other in two different HTML elements with different IDs. But what actually happening is the forced layout of one is interfering with the other one.

What I have tried:

1. Wrapping the whole code in a single function and then calling it twice, still messing.
2. Making two different functions with two different names and then calling each of them but it is also messing up the layout.

These are the functions which are updating the code:

```
function draw (varname) {
      var centers = getCenters(varname, [width, height]);
      force.on("tick", tick(centers, varname));
      labels(centers)
      force.start();
    }

function tick (centers, varname) {
      var foci = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < centers.length; i++) {
        foci[centers[i].name] = centers[i];
      }
      return function (e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var o = data[i];
          var f = foci[o[varname]];
          o.y += ((f.y + (f.dy / 2)) - o.y) * e.alpha;
          o.x += ((f.x + (f.dx / 2)) - o.x) * e.alpha;
        }

        nodes.each(collide(.2))
          .attr("transform", function(d){ //<-- use transform it's not a g
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });
      }
    }


function collide(alpha) {
          var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
          return function (d) {
            var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
                nx1 = d.x - r,
                nx2 = d.x + r,
                ny1 = d.y - r,
                ny2 = d.y + r;
            quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
              if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                    y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                    l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                    r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding;
                if (l < r) {
                  l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
                  d.x -= x *= l;
                  d.y -= y *= l;
                  quad.point.x += x;
                  quad.point.y += y;
                }
              }
              return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
            });
          };
```

Maybe some variables or some elements are either global or are interfering with each other but I am not able to figure it out. Need some help with this..

Pasting the complete code here:

start('active');

```
function start(type) {
      var data = response.content_affinity.categories;
      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
      {
        data[i]["sentiment"] = data[i].positive_sentiment>55?"Positive":"Negative";
        data[i]["source"] = "twitter";
        data[i]["retweet_count"] = data[i]["share"];
      }

      var data2 = response.content_affinity.categories;
      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
      {
        data2[i]["sentiment"] = data2[i].positive_sentiment>55?"Positive":"Negative";
        data2[i]["source"] = "twitter";
        data2[i]["retweet_count"] = data2[i]["share"];
      }

      dataAPI = data;

      var d3Instances = 0;
      create(data, {id:"#bubble_content_cate_ga"}, d3Instances);

      d3Instances++;
      create(data2.slice(0,4), {id:"#bubble_content_cate_ga_2"}, d3Instances);

}


function create(data_, obj, d3i) {

    var data = data_.concat();

    $(obj.id).empty();

    var group = size = color = '';
    group = "";
    color = 'sentiment';
    size = "retweet_count";

    var colorTheme = {positive:"#6BBA9B", negative:"#6BBA9B", neutral:"#C93946", "default":"#ECF0F1"}


    var dataAPI, colors;


    colors = {

      sentiment: {
          Positive: "#6BBA9B",
          Neutral: "#ffffff",
          Negative: "#C93946"
        },
        "default": colorTheme["default"] 
    };
    var radius = 75;
    var width = $(obj.id).width();
    var height = $(obj.id).height();
    var fill = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['#FF00CC','#FF00CC','#00FF00','#00FF00','#FFFF00','#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000','#7F0000']);
    var svg = d3.select(obj.id).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
        /*var _html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12 text-center heading-widget">Widget Title</div></div>'
                +'<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12 text-center"><button class="groupItems btn button-widget-bubblegraph">Classify</button></div></div>'
        $().prepend(_html);*/
    data = getDataMapping(data, size);
    console.log(data);
    var padding = 5;
    var maxRadius = d3.max(_.pluck(data, 'radius'));

    var maximums = {
          retweet_count: d3.max(_.pluck(data, 'retweet_count')),
      volume: d3.max(_.pluck(data, 'volume')),
      lasPrice: d3.max(_.pluck(data, 'lastPrice')),
      standardDeviation: d3.max(_.pluck(data, 'standardDeviation'))
    };

    var getCenters = function (vname, size) {
        var centers, map;
        centers = _.uniq(_.pluck(data, vname)).map(function (d) {
          return {name: d, value: 1};
        });

        map = d3.layout.treemap().size(size).ratio(1/1);
        map.nodes({children: centers});

        return centers;
    };



    var defs = svg.append("defs");

    var filter = defs.append("filter").attr("id", "drop-shadow").attr("height", "130%");
    filter.append("feGaussianBlur").attr("in", "SourceAlpha").attr("stdDeviation", 5).attr("result", "blur");
    filter.append("feOffset").attr("in", "blur").attr("dx", 5).attr("dy", 5).attr("result", "offsetBlur"); 
    var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge"); 
    feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "offsetBlur") ;
    feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "SourceGraphic");




        var nodes = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(data);

        var g = nodes.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "bubbleParentg_"+d3i)
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            showPopover.call(this, d);
          })
          .on("click", function(d) {
            doTheFiltering.call(this, d);
          })
          .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            removePopovers();
          });

        g.append("circle")
          .attr("class", function (d, i) { return " circle_"+d.sentiment+" circle_"+i})

          .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
          .style('fill', function(d) {
           return colors["sentiment"][d["sentiment"]];
           })
          .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)");


          g.append("text")
            .attr("dy",".35em")
            .attr("dx",function(d){
                return "-"+(d.radius-d.radius/5)+"px";
            })
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .text(function(d){
                return d.category.formatEntity();
            })
            .style("font-size", function(d) { 
                console.log(this.getComputedTextLength());
                return Math.min(2 * d.radius, (2 * d.radius - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength() * 12) + "px"; 
            });



    function getDataMapping(data, vname) {
      var max = d3.max(_.pluck(data, vname));

      for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        //data[j].radius = (vname != '') ? radius * (data[j][vname] / max) : 15;
        data[j].radius = (data.length-2*j+20)*2.5;
        data[j].x = data[j].x ? data[j].x : Math.random() * width;
        data[j].y = data[j].y ? data[j].y : Math.random() * height;
        data[j].sentiment = data[j].sentiment;
      }

      return data;
    }


    var force = d3.layout.force();


    var tick = function(centers, varname) {
      var foci = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < centers.length; i++) {
        foci[centers[i].name] = centers[i];
      }
      return function (e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var o = data[i];
          var f = foci[o[varname]];
          o.y += ((f.y + (f.dy / 2)) - o.y) * e.alpha;
          o.x += ((f.x + (f.dx / 2)) - o.x) * e.alpha;
        }

        svg.selectAll("g.bubbleParentg_"+d3i).each(collide(.2))
          .attr("transform", function(d){ //<-- use transform it's not a g
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });
      }
    }

    draw("");

    function draw (varname) {
      var centers = getCenters(varname, [width, height]);

      console.log(centers);
      force.on("tick", tick(centers, varname));
      //labels(centers)
      force.start();
    }






    function doTheFiltering(d){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(d);

        data.forEach(function(el, i){
            if(el.category == d.category){
                data[i]["filtering"] = "true";
            }
            else{
                data[i]["filtering"] = "false";
            }
        });

        draw("filtering");
        showInnerCat(d.category);
    }

    function collide(alpha) {
      var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
      return function (d) {
        var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
            nx1 = d.x - r,
            nx2 = d.x + r,
            ny1 = d.y - r,
            ny2 = d.y + r;
        quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
          if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
            var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding;
            if (l < r) {
              l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
              d.x -= x *= l;
              d.y -= y *= l;
              quad.point.x += x;
              quad.point.y += y;
            }
          }
          return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
        });
      };
    }


  }




    function returnTweets(dataPiece){
            return   '<span style="font-weight:800; font-size:17px; display:inline-block;" class="color_yellow"> <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw" style="color:#cccccc;"></i> '+dataPiece.count+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>'
                     +'<span style="font-weight:800; font-size:17px; display:inline-block;"  class="color_red"> <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-fw" style="color:#cccccc;"></i> '+Math.round(dataPiece.positive_sentiment)+'%</span>';

    }




    function removePopovers (a, reinit) {

          var _curr = a;
          $('.popover').each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
          }); 

    }


    function showPopover (d) {


          removePopovers(this, false);
          d3.selectAll("circle").classed("selectedCircle", false);  
          $(this).popover({
            placement: 'auto top',
            container: 'body',
            trigger: 'manual',
            position:"fixed",
            html : true,
            content: function() { 
              return returnTweets(d);
            }
          });
          $(this).popover('show');
          $(".popover").addClass(d.sentiment+"_border");



    }
```

Comment: You need to show more code than this. Could you also create a jsfiddle or something like that?

Comment: Your problem is most likely related to your DOM elements selectors, like the variable `nodes`. However the code excerpt that you have included does not show how these are set...

Comment: @MehdiElFadil I have pasted the complete code.. Please have a look :)

Comment: @MehdiElFadil Sir did you find anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't have the time right now to create a jsfiddle and create sample data in order to debug your code, sorry.

Comment: @MehdiElFadil Okay thanks anyway. Give it a shot whenever you get some time.. Kind of stuck here..

Comment: **The still isn't complete, reproducible code.** I just tried running it and get `Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined`...

Comment: @Mark let me create a fiddle for this..